# Multiple Levels for Modular Forms?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Please pardon what I'm sure is a very naive question. I have heard discussions of modular forms for a bit and am trying to get a more fundamental understanding. People often talk about modular forms of level $N$. I have read that this means that the finite subgroup $\Gamma$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on which the modular form $f$ is defined contains the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$. We can think of this subgroup as the set of matrices congruent to the identity modulo $N$. My question is this: couldn't this be true for multiple values of $N$? In other words, can a given modular form have multiple levels? Yet people seem to generally refer to a modular form as having a specific level. Is this just because we are usually interested in a specific canonical value of $N$? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is a modular form with respect to the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$, then $f$ is also a modular form with respect to $\Gamma(\ell N)$ for any $\ell$. The converse is not true.

The natural place to talk about a modular form is the smallest level in which it can occur. There is a more technical definition, which is that the "natural" modular forms associated to a cannonical level $N$ are the "newforms" of level $N$. See [this page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkin%E2%80%93Lehner_theory) for example. The [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/) only displays information about newforms.

It might also be helpful to note that this is very similar to Dirichlet characters. Recall the mechanical definition of a mod $N$ Dirichlet character as a multiplicative function $\chi : \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ that satisfies $\chi(n) = \chi(n + N)$ and $\chi(n) = 0$ if $\gcd(n, N) > 1$.

For example, we have $\chi_{-4}(n) := (\frac{-4}{n})$, defined to have $\chi_{-4}(1) = 1$, $\chi_{-4}(3) = -1$, and $\chi_{-4}(n) = 0$ otherwise. Then $\chi_{-4}$ is a Dirichlet character mod $4$, but it's also a Dirichlet character mod $20$, or $444$, or any multiple of $4$. The analogous notion of "level" and "newform" with characters is "conductor" and "primitive character".